# Include dollar sign + number in Atom snippet

Tags: atom-editor, code-snippets

I would like to use a snippet in my c++ code to quickly place an interrupt for debugging:

```
asm("int $3");
```

So I have to add to snippets.json

```
'.source.cpp':
  'debugint':
    'prefix': 'debugint'
    'body': 'asm("int $3");'
```

Of course the $3 gets interpreted as a snippet variable. Is there a way to get the snippet working. $$ does not work as the output is

```
asm("int $");
```

Comment: Does it support extended asm?  You could try something like `asm("int %0" : : "i"(3));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks David Wohlferd, this pointed me into the right direction!

snippets.json:

```
'body': 'asm("int $${1:3}");'
```

leads to the correct code snippet:

```
asm("int $3");
```